# Angular-material md-select cuts off background to edge of content?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I updated to angular-material 0.9 and now when I open md-select it cuts off the background to the edge of the content. Is there some way to avoid this?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNOypa

```
<div class="background">
<div layout="column" layout-align="center center" flex>
  <md-select placeholder="Pick">
    <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
  </md-select>
    </div>
  <p>The background ends at the content when md-select is open</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with changing

```
 height:100%;
```

to

```
height:100vh;
```

A similar question: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)